# AS3: How to access a property/method from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class

new to Actionscript, OOP, this forum, etc!! I have a large project I'm working on, very text and button heavy. I want to create an array of strings in a text class that I can access with the main document class. Then I'll be able to populate a text field with items in the array. The purpose of this is to avoid having massive lines of text in my main document... but I can't even get my test to work. The compiler is telling me that the array (txt1) is undefined. First here's my code for the array:

```
  //text array class:format5000
  package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.text.*; 
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

    public class format5000 extends MovieClip {

        private var txt1:Array = [];

    public function format5000 () {
        // constructor code
        txt1[0] = "This is the first txt string";
        trace("format loaded");
        trace(txt1[0]);
} } }
```

And here's the code for the main doc:

```
 //main doc class: text5001
 package  {

   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.display.*;
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.text.*; 


  public class text5001 extends MovieClip{

        private var myText:TextField;
        private var theformat:format5000;

  public function text5001() {
        // constructor code

        theformat = new format5000();

        addChild(theformat);
        myText = new TextField();
        myText.text = txt1[0];
        myText.x = 50;
        myText.y = 50;
        addChild(myText);
        trace("text loading..."); 
} } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that keyword `private` in front of the variable? That means the variable only works within the object and cannot be accessed outside the object.

You could declare the variable as `public` instead, and then you could access it with dot notation like so: `theformat.txt1[0]`

However, public variables are kind of a bad practice, so you might be better off restructuring your code such that the array doesn't need to be accessed outside the object it exists in. I mean, you didn't explain what the format5000 class is for; I would create a method createTextfield() in format5000 and then call that method from the main class.

So in format5000 I would write

```
public function createTextField(index:int):TextField {
  var myText:TextField = new TextField();
  myText.text = txt1[index];
  return myText;
}
```

and then in text5001

```
theformat = new format5000();
myText = theformat.createTextField(0);
myText.x = 50;
myText.y = 50;
addChild(myText);
```

Comment: Genius! I'm extremely grateful. Out of curiosity, I tried changing the access to "public", which worked. But I want to exercise best practice from the get-go, so I instead took your advice and created a function within the format5000 class. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the Stack!. This var should be public so other classes can access it.

```
private var txt1:Array = [];
```

should be

```
public var txt1:Array = [];
```

so your line of code would be:

```
myText.text = theformat.txt1[0];
```

Comment: I don't know where you got `root` from, the code would be `theformat.txt1[0]`

Comment: hm, it looks like that was edited but there's no notice about the edit